# $L^2([0,+\infty))$ function which is slower than $e^{-x}$ when $x\rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could any one give me an example which is a $L^2([0,+\infty))$ function, but it has a slower decay than exponential type functions like $e^{-x}$ when $x\rightarrow +\infty$? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $e^{-2x}$? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Kaster This is not what I want, but still thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f \colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbf R$ by $$ f(x) := \frac 1{x+1}. $$
Then $f \in L^2([0, \infty))$, and 
$$ \frac{\exp(-x)}{f(x)} = \frac{x+1}{e^x} \to 0 $$

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realize how stupid this questions is. I confused myself after working the whole night:) I will close this question.